# Angular return results from google PlacesService and add to Observable

Tags: angular, firebase, observable, google-places-api

Using the method below I can successfully retrieve place details with placeId.

```
getPlaceDetails(placeId) {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($('#service-helper').get(0));
      service.getDetails({'placeId': placeId}, (results, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          if (results) {
            console.log(results);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

I have another method that I use for retrieving all of my customers from Firebase (Firestore) and I'm trying to add the details I receive from getPlaceDetails by passing each placeId but I'm not sure how to get the results from getPlaceDetails and add them to each installer when being mapped.  My goal would be for getInstallers() to return something like return {id, ...data, ...results}  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
getInstallers(): Observable<Installer[]> {
    const installersCollection = this.afs.collection<Installer>('installers');
    return installersCollection.snapshotChanges().map(installers => {
      return installers.map(i => {
        const data = i.payload.doc.data() as Installer;
        const id = i.payload.doc.id;
        this.getPlaceDetails(data.placeId);
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
  }
```

Here's a very simplified version of it on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-23mu7g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey this is a working solution:

[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dstuyp?file=app/app.component.ts)

Please, when you have the need to interact directly with the DOM use the angular way, this line is not recomended (it use Jquery):

```
const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($('#service-helper').get(0));
```

Angular way:

```
@ViewChild('serviceHelper') serviceHelper;
```

And since you are changing the values of paginator and sort directives, you can get this error: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` you should fire the `detecChanges()` method but first import the `changeDetectorRef`:

```
import { ..., ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Just keep in mind that when your are getting a direct reference to an element in the DOM (using `@ViewChild` decorator), they are not complete reliable until `ngAfterViewInit` is executed. **app.component.ts**

```
    import {Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    ...
    @ViewChild('serviceHelper') serviceHelper;
    ...

    constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Create 100 users
    const businesses = [
        {placeId: 'ChIJHWJmnEbxxokRxI5WpqIW9jo'},
        {placeId: 'ChIJeUdT2ikPK4cRpqJK61nKvuk'},
        {placeId: 'ChIJ24q4qLMsDogRkwzJD2maZcw'},
    ];

    const updatedBusinesses = []

    businesses.forEach(business => {
        this.getPlaceDetails(business.placeId)
            .subscribe(place => {
                console.log(place);
                updatedBusinesses.push({
                    placeId: business.placeId,
                    name: place.name,
                    rating: place.rating
                });
                // Assign the data to the data source for the table to render
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(updatedBusinesses);
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
                this.ref.detectChanges();
            });
    })
  }
...
getPlaceDetails(placeId): Observable<any> {
    const callback = (results, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          if (results) {
            return results;
          }
        }
      };

    return this.loadMapsApi().pipe(concatMap(place => {
        const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.serviceHelper.nativeElement);
        let $getDetailsAsObservable : any;

        $getDetailsAsObservable = bindCallback(service.getDetails.bind(service), callback);
        return $getDetailsAsObservable({'placeId': placeId}); 
    }));
  }

  loadMapsApi(): Observable<any> {
      const $mapsAPILoader = fromPromise(this.mapsAPILoader.load());
      return $mapsAPILoader;
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
...
    <div id="service-helper" #serviceHelper></div>
...
```

Comment: I was asking more about populating the material data table with the results I get from the google places api for each business.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check the live example.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much for your help!  I haven't implemented it into my app yet but I can tell just from looking at it that this points me in the right direction.